# Updating timestamp of row if exists in HBase

Tags: java, hbase, lru

TL;DR: Is it possible to update a row timestamp if it exists?

Is it possible to make HBase act in an LRU fashion? What I mean by that is that if a row exists in HBase I want to update its timestamp

I know I can invoke a create data if it doesn't exist (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400393/hbase-atomic-check-row-does-not-exist-and-create-operation)) but I'm looking for the opposite, updating data (specifically the timestamp) if the data does exist

The reason for wanting to do this is that I'm working on a component which uses HBase as a cache for URLs and their content, this way when a new request for a URL arrives I want to check if the content already exists and if it does I want to update its timestamp, otherwise the content doesn't exist and I want to go and actually fetch it. The reason I need the timestamp is for the other side of this program where I have a component that reads all the URLs that arrived in the last day, that's the reason why I also need to update this timestamp

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a case for [`checkAndMutate`](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndMutate(byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[],%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter.CompareOp,%20byte[],%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RowMutations)). It should be available in `hbase` 0.98.7+

Comment: @Shyam is there a way to update the timestamp without first using a get to get the values and then using another put?

Comment: Also checkAndMutate checks for a specific value in a row while I just want to know if the row exists or not

Comment: Quoting from javadoc _"If the passed value is null, the check is for the lack of column (ie: non-existence)"_ . Couldn't you rely the opposite condition of it. i.e pass some dummy/sentinel condition and value to the `checkAndMutate` method, Such that it will hold true if the column exists. (Existence check in a not so straight forward way). *EDIT: * Did I understand the case correctly, `if(exists) "update ts" else "do something else and then update row"`?

Comment: The problem is that if the row exists I have no way of knowing what its value will contain so negating the condition is not possible - I can probably add a dummy value that I can check for it but I don't feel like adding extra info to my data. You got it almost right `if (exists) "update ts" else "do a lot of other things that will eventually create the row"` - I'm sort of trying to use it as LRU cache (with the timestamp). Should I edit my question if it's not clear enough?

Comment: I think I get it. I agree that using `checkAndMutate` would be abusing the api in this case. ( There is a discussion about it's behaviour [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-15260) ). There was a proposal to have better 'AtomicOps' api, which didn't really go through.  I think it's better to settle for `if(table.exists(Get)) { new Put; }` for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did go for the table exists and put :). I was just wondering if there's more to the API than what I'm familiar  with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been so long since I posted this question but I figured I'll at least accept what I ended up using (even though it was not what I was hoping to use)

I ended up just sending a get and then put so the timestamp is automatically increased